# Passing down a variable in a hover function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, hover

I'm doing a very simple hover function for a button and I need to pas down a variable. I can use the variable in the first state of the hover but not in the second. Does it have something to do with the fact that the variable is defined locally and not available in within that second function?

Here's the code:

```
$('#'+'[id^="world_map"]').hover(function() {

    var that2 = this.id;

    $('#' +that2+ '_thumbnail_container').animate({"opacity" : 1}, 150, function() { });
    $('#' +that2+ '_thumbnail_container').css('visibility','visible');

        },                  


    function() {
    $('#' +that2+ '_thumbnail_container').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 150, function() { });

    $('#' +that2+ '_thumbnail_container').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it is because the variable `that2` is defined in the scope of the first function. However, the value (`this.id`) itself is available in both methods.

```
$('#'+'[id^="world_map"]').hover(function() {


    $('#' +this.id + '_thumbnail_container').animate({"opacity" : 1}, 150, function() { });
    $('#' +this.id+ '_thumbnail_container').css('visibility','visible');

        },                  


    function() {
    $('#' +this.id+ '_thumbnail_container').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 150, function() { });

    $('#' +this.id+ '_thumbnail_container').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

Comment: aha so (this) passes down all the time? Thank you!

Comment: `this` is *always* a reference to the DOM object (NOT the jQuery object).